CSS Sprites in WordPress
The code below shows the use of a sprite that should normally display images in B&W and when the mouse is hovered over the images, they become colored, but without showing the transitions between the images. It would only change color.
What can be done to not show the transitions?
This appears in the sidebar of our website:
https://materiaincognita.com.br/
The code is in this text file as follows:
<head>
<style>

#social {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px;
}

#social li, #social a {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 60px;
    height: 56px;
}

#facebook {
    left: 0px;
    background: url('https://materiaincognita.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2024/11/redes-sociais.jpg') -0 -0;
}

#pinterest {
    left: 0px;
    background: url('https://materiaincognita.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2024/11/redes-sociais.jpg') -60px -0;
}

#bluesky {
    left: 0px;
    background: url('https://materiaincognita.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2024/11/redes-sociais.jpg') -120px -0;
}

#youtube {
    left: 0px;
    background: url('https://materiaincognita.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2024/11/redes-sociais.jpg') -180px -0;
}

#instagram {
    left: 0px;
    background: url('https://materiaincognita.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2024/11/redes-sociais.jpg') -240px -0;
}

#facebook a:hover {
    left: 0px;
    background: url('https://materiaincognita.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2024/11/redes-sociais.jpg') -0 -60px;
}

#pinterest a:hover {
    left: 0px;
    background: url('https://materiaincognita.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2024/11/redes-sociais.jpg') -60px -60px;
}

#bluesky a:hover {
    left: 0px;
    background: url('https://materiaincognita.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2024/11/redes-sociais.jpg') -120px -60px;
}

#youtube a:hover {
    left: 0px;
    background: url('https://materiaincognita.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2024/11/redes-sociais.jpg') -180px -60px;
}

#instagram a:hover {
    left: 0px;
    background: url('https://materiaincognita.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2024/11/redes-sociais.jpg') -240px -60px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="social">
<ul>
<li id="facebook"><a title="Facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/materia.incognita" target="_blank" rel="noopener"></a></li>
<li id="pinterest"><a title="Pinterest" href="https://br.pinterest.com/materiaincog" target="_blank" rel="noopener"></a></li>
<li id="bluesky"><a title="Bluesky" href="https://bsky.app/profile/materia-incognita.bsky.social" target="_blank" rel="noopener"></a></li>
<li id="youtube"><a title="YouTube" href="https://www.youtube.com/user/materiaincognita" target="_blank" rel="noopener"></a></li>
<li id="instagram"><a title="Instagram" href="https://www.instagram.com/materia.incognita/" target="_blank" rel="noopener"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>

However, if I put my code in "CodePen dot io" it works perfectly as I want.
The problem seems to be inside WordPress system…
Any idea to solve the problem?

Inspect your site where the problem is occurring, and look for any transition style rules, then add your own rules to overwrite those (assuming they're in a default style and you can't just remove them)

You need to add the CSS rule #social a, #social a:hover { transition:none !important; } like Johanes explains below. Also, there are some misalignment to adjust on the Y axis for your sprites when hovered: The hovered values for Y axis are -58px for all, instead of -60px (except for #instagram a:hover which correct value is -57px).

Hi, DBS and LoicTheAztec. Thanks for your replies. I've changed the height of the image and aligned it better. Everything is perfect now. Thank you again!!!

There is a css rule for a in your website that contains transition settings.
To avoid the transition, add transition: none; to the css rule for #social a. If that still doesn't work, add !important, i.e. transition: none !important;

Thanks, Johannes. Everything is OK now!  :)
